# Alternative for "dead-end job" that is not disrespectful

Tags: expressions

A position with a company may be high paying with lots of perks, but otherwise offer no opportunity for growth. Some might consider this a "dead-end job" but that has a negative connotation. Is there a term for such a position that honors the post?

Reading through Wikipedia on [dead-end job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead-end_job) is interesting but points to no positive term. I'm wondering if such a thing exists.

Thanks.

EDIT: I think "limited growth opportunity" is the best fit so far (from the comments).

Comment: You pretty much said it yourself, but that can be shortened to "limited growth opportunity".

Comment: Oh, I like that.

Comment: There can't be a positive term, but Kristina's suggestion is far less starkly negative.

Comment: A "high-paying job with lots of perks" sounds like a "good job" (but maybe not a career).

Comment: The closest I can think of is "sinecure" which has the sense of stagnation and high pay you're after, but also carries a connotation of easiness and more than a whiff of nepotism, which probably isn't what you have in mind.

Comment: We also use "day job" to refer to a pointless or boring job that pays the bills, but it also usually implies that you're doing it to support some non-lucrative passion (like being a comedian).

Comment: Maybe folks from [workplace.se] would know better. Try sharing this question in their chat room.

Comment: The person who holds a job described as "dead-end" should not rake himself over the coals. There are any number of reasons why a given job does not promise future advancement: The employer may be a family business staffed largely by family members. The employer may be in a depressed area and barely able to keep from shutting its doors. The condition of the economy may militate against expansion for the employer. And on and on ... The term "dead-end" is not a dig against the holder of the job.

Answer (score 1):

You could say "I don't want to be a office worker", but that would include more that just dead-end jobs, or maybe "I don't want to be a menial employee". Somewhat negative, less so that dead-end job, or "Temporary employee". That would probably be the one you want.

A tip for looking through a Wikipedia page, look at the sources as well!!

EDITS:
Seems like your example of a dead-end job will get you somewhere, that makes a broken question. From italki.com, [Question here](https://www.italki.com/question/106968) 
"If something 'won't get you anywhere' ,it means this thing is useless and it is not worth doing it or pursuing it. 
"
 And that is some copy pasta for you!
As you can see, your job is still worth doing, it does not fit very well with dead-end job.

Limited growth opportunity seems best, but the asker(Sp. Cker. says i cant put er on, HELP) is not satisfied.

Comment: +1 for the answer, but not what I was looking for.

Comment: Any of the see-also pages on the wiki are good word by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be in usage, but I would suggest **career path terminus** (or possibly "career *track* terminus") as a neutral description of farthest place you will reach in a given career.  The analogy is with "terminal degree" meaning the highest degree in a given professional track.

> This is a prestigious position, but be aware it's basically a *career path terminus*.

"Terminal career" would be briefer, but that sounds terrible.  If you wanted something similar with a positive (rather than neutral) sound, you could go with "career path *apex*."

Answer (score 1):

Though it it hard to find a formal definition, I think ***steady job*** or ***stable job*** fit the bill.

Both give continuity, both lack excitement.